# What Java libraries are suitable for graphing math functions including SDEs

Tags: java, performance, graphics, statistics, stochastic

Ideally would want libraries that handle creating graphs on screen well.  For now these would be read-only, but eventually we may want to re-draw based on user GUI manipulations.

The other side of the story is SDEs.  Would appreciate comments on any experiences people have of SDE calculations and modelling of stochastic math projections using Java.  What are the likely performance tradeoff scenarios?

Would prefer to rely on widely used libraries if possible.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jgraph is the general standard. 
http://www.jgraph.com/